# How to know Magic Mouse 2 is charging properly?

Tags: battery, mouse, charging

When I connect my Magic Mouse 2 to the wall socket through a lighting cable, there is no indicator to show that it is charging. It has been some time and I don't see it working yet. Is there a way to know that it is charging indeed?

(It could be an issue with the lightning cable as well, but I have no other device to test it with)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What device do you have that you use your Magic Mouse with?

Comment: It's a Macbook Pro. The issue isn't with the Bluetooth connection. Version 1 of the magic mouse had a small light indicator which displayed when it was switched on (and no light when zero battery). In this current version though, there is no indicator AFAIK.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlike the first generation Magic Mouse, there is no indicator present on the Magic Mouse 2 that would indicate the charging status.

But if you have access to a Mac (which is with which you are most likely using your Magic Mouse), you can use it to check if your Magic Mouse is charging.

Start by pairing your Magic Mouse to your Mac and checking the battery status in either one of the following places:

1. Click on the Bluetooth icon towards the right of the macOS Menu Bar. Hover the mouse pointer over the entry corresponding to the Magic Mouse and see the current battery charge level.

   [image]
2. Go to System Preferences → Mouse and look for the current battery charge level at the bottom of the window.

   [image]

Now charge your Magic Mouse 2 for a little while which you can do either using a wall outlet or Mac. Disconnect and check the charge status again to confirm if the Magic Mouse is indeed charging.

Alternatively, you can have the Mouse System Preference pane open and connect the Magic Mouse 2 using the Lightning cable, and the battery indicator would change to show that the Mouse is charging.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a detailed reply there. The last one is what I was looking for. I connected the mouse to my Mac (had to look for a USB-C to USB adapter), and that showed the battery indicator turn into charging one. Point to note though, that for the duration when the mouse is charging its bluetooth connection disconnects.

Comment: Sadly not very useful on iPad. There is a battery indicator if you swipe left from the Home Screen but it only shows this when the mouse is *not* charging with a wall plug. I’ve just got a used mouse. For now I’ve connected a USB ammeter to the Lightning cable. I’m hoping to see the Amps drop from 0.19A to 0.00A when it’s fully charged 